# Show $\phi: \mathbb F_3 \times \mathbb F_3 \rightarrow R$ given by $\phi(a,b) = a\epsilon_1 +b\epsilon_2$ is bijective, $a,b \in \mathbb F_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Show $\phi: \mathbb F_3 \times\mathbb F_3 \rightarrow R$ given by $\phi(a,b) = a\epsilon_1 +b\epsilon_2$ is bijective, $a,b \in \mathbb F_3$.

$R = \mathbb F_3[X]/\langle X^2 -1\rangle$ and $\epsilon_1 = \alpha - 1, \epsilon_2 = -\alpha - 1$ for $\alpha = [X] \in R$.

I've already proved $\phi$ is surjective by: $[x] = [a^{'}X+b^{'}] \in R$ then $\phi(2a^{'}+b^{'}, a^{'}+b^{'})=[x]$.

However I'm having trouble showing that $\phi$ is injective. By the way I know $\epsilon_{1,2}$ and $\pm \alpha$ are zero divisors and units, respectively.

Thanks.

Comment: Since you've already shown your map to be surjective and both ${\mathbb F}_3 \times {\mathbb F}_3$ and $R$ contain 9 elements, you're already done.

Comment: May I ask why ? Is it because that without injective, then $\phi$ couldn't be surjective. Or how do I state this formally ?

Answer (score 3):

Let's look this from an abstract point of view. So, let $F$ be a field, $R=F[X]/(X^2-1)$, $\alpha=[X]\in R$, $\varepsilon_1=\alpha-1$, $\varepsilon_2=-\alpha-1$.

The map $\varphi\colon F\times F\to R$ defined by
$$
f(a,b)=a\varepsilon_1+b\varepsilon_2
$$
is of course $F$-linear; $R$ is generated by $1$ and $\alpha$; so in order to show it's surjective, we need to find
$$
a(\alpha-1)+b(-\alpha-1)=1
$$
so $a-b=0$ and $a+b=-1$. The similar system for $\alpha$ gives $a-b=1$ and $a+b=0$. The systems are both solvable if and only if the characteristic of $F$ is different from $2$.

So the map $\varphi$ is surjective whenever $\operatorname{char}F\ne2$. Being a linear map between two-dimensional vector spaces, it is also injective.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way of proving injectivity:

$\Phi$ is injective, if the only element that is mapped to $\bar 0 \in R$ is $(0,0) \in \Bbb F_3 \times \Bbb F_3$. So let's have a look at the elements that get mapped to $\bar 0$, ie. the *kernel* of $\Phi$:

\begin{align}
\ker \Phi & = \{(a,b) \in \Bbb F_3 \times \Bbb F_3 \mid \Phi(a,b) = \bar 0\} \\
& = \{a (\alpha -1) + b (-\alpha -1) = \bar 0 \mid (a,b) \in \Bbb F_3 \times \Bbb F_3 \}\\
& = \{a \alpha - a + b (-\alpha) - b = \bar 0 \mid (a,b) \in \Bbb F_3 \times \Bbb F_3 \}\\
& = \{\alpha(a-b) -(a+b) = \bar 0 \mid (a,b) \in \Bbb F_3 \times \Bbb F_3 \} \\
& = \{(a,b)= (0,0) \in \Bbb F_3 \times \Bbb F_3\}
\end{align}
which you can verify by taking all possible $(a,b) \in \Bbb F_3 \times \Bbb F_3$ and modding out $\alpha^2 -1$.

Comment: If I understand your argument correctly (pretty new in this field), you have shown $\ker \phi = \{(0,0) = e \in \mathbb F_3 \times \mathbb F_3 \}$ which implies $\phi$ is injective using group theory (homomorphism). Does this also apply to $\phi$ ? To be honest, I don't know if $\phi$ is a group or a ring homomorphism ? The problem only states "show that the function $\phi$ is bijective", nothing else.

Comment: The problem I have with this solution is the last step. All the preceding ones were ok, and relatively easy, but how did you justify this leap? Warning: if you replace $\Bbb{F}_3$ with $\Bbb{F}_2$ it is incorrect, so the argument has to reflect that somehow.

Comment: Maybe I was too quick, but actually you have the relations $a-b = \alpha$ and $a+b=1$ *or* $a-b = 0$ and $a+b = 0$. The first one isn't possible, since $a,b \in \Bbb F_3$ and the second one yields $a=b$, hence $2a = 0$, which is only possible for $a = b = 0$. If you take $\Bbb F_2$, you get the extra solution $a=b=1$ for this, hence no injectivity.